# Не выполняется скрипт по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Есть проблема с AJAX  подключением и выводом данных JSON , без него кнопка работает по принципу : нажал одни раз - записалась 1 (загорелась зеленым), нажал второй раз - записалась 0 (загорелась серым) . Говорю сразу что я новичок в этом деле по этому пожалуйста не судите строго за корявый код . Что здесь не так ,подправьте пожалуйста (

```
<button  id="test1" onclick="myEvent1()"><p id="text1" style="position:absolute;color:black;top:6px;left:30px;font-size:30px;">РАБОТА</p></button>

<div id="result1">0</div>

<!--СКРИПТ ajax  для кнопок вкл, выкл -->
<script>
let result1 = 0;
let myEvent1 = function() {
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 

var n_JSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
var ID = n_JSON.ID;
var result1 = n_JSON.result1;{   
  if (ID == "1" , result1 == "0") {
 document.getElementById('test1').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
    result1 = 1;
document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;    
document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
document.getElementById('test4').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result4 = 0;      
  } else {
 document.getElementById('test1').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result1 = 0;
document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
document.getElementById('test4').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result4 = 0; 
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = result1;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
    document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = result3;
    document.getElementById('result4').innerHTML = result4;
  }
    }
      }
        }
var oncl1 = document.getElementById("test1").value; 
xmlhttp.open("GET","connect-button/button-data.php?test1="+oncl1,true);
xmlhttp.send();     
}
</script>
```

подключение

connect-button/button-data.php

```
<?php
if(($_GET['result1']=="0")){

    $click = '{"ID":"1", "result1":"0"}';

if(($_GET['result1']=="1")){

    $click = '{"ID":"1", "result1":"1"}';   
}
?>
```

Comment: Это метод передачи данных на сколько я понял .

Comment: @Anamnian а что такое `AJAX` по вашему?

Comment: вообще это метод обмена данными между браузером и сервером  с использованием своего синтаксиса .

Comment: Так вы поможете что так ,а что не так ?

Comment: Извините,я не силен в php и не знаю, что такое `id в (php my admin)`

Answer (score 0):

Может быть стоит строку

```
if (ID == "1", result1 == "0") {
```

заменить на

```
if (ID == "1" && result1 == "0") {
```

или

```
if (ID == "1" || result1 == "0") {
```

Comment: Эм.. А где ты эту строку нашёл?

Comment: Есть там такая строка . Думаете проблема только в этом ,весь остальной код нормальный ?